# VTK vtkStructuredPoints GetPointData() SetScalars

Tags: c++, vtk

How to set sclar in new version VTK. How to convert new version VTK below code?

```
StructuredPoints->GetPointData()->SetScalars(scalars);
```

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing what version you are referring too, I think both methods you are using are still available in VTK:

- [GetPointData](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataSet.html#aaf5f8853184dda29249e240aa4cd2c33)
- [SetScalars](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataSetAttributes.html#a426009e9d6ac5a4b2cda670aed78042d)